# How to read line with variable from file?

Tags: shell

How to read line with variable from file and assign variable through a loop? My file has line `xyz_$loop`, now my script has to read line from file `xyz_$loop` and then while looping print `xyz_1`, `xyz_2`, `xyz_3`, etc.
I am using shell script my file URL1 contain loop_$i 
my script -->

```
while read p; do
  max=10
  for (( i=2; i <= $max; ++i )) do
    echo $p
  done
done <URL1
```

print following output

```
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
```

but I need output

```
loop_2
loop_3
loop_4
```

Comment: Show some code or we have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: my file URL1 contain loop_$i

my script 

while read p; do
max=10
for (( i=2; i <= $max; ++i ))
do
    echo $p
done
done <URL1

print 

loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i

but I need output 
loop_2
loop_3
loop_4
.

Comment: This should be in the body of the question. [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46672795/edit) and show what you have done.

Comment: It's not at all clear how you're getting the output you claim from the code you provided. That said, *in general*, we already have a lot of questions that cover the ground of indirect variable assignment and expansion in depth; it's not at all clear that what you're asking presents something new.

Comment: ...if you *do* have a new question that isn't covered in the dupes, please edit your code to comply with the [mcve] definition, so folks can reproduce the behavior themselves (via copy-and-paste).

Answer (score -1):

You will probably want to replace '$loop' with the index of your loop

```
// read your file    

$i = 0;
foreach($fileLines as $fileLine)
{
    $fileLine = str_replace('$loop', $i, $fileLine);

    $i++;
}
```

Edit: I did make the assumption that you are using php.

Comment: I am using shell script

my file URL1 contain loop_$i

my script 

while read p; do
max=10
for (( i=2; i <= $max; ++i ))
do
    echo $p
done
done <URL1

print following ouput

loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i
loop_$i

but I need output 
loop_2
loop_3
loop_4
.

Comment: The question is tagged "shell" and this looks like some variant of the Bourne shell.